# Go: Check if every item in a slice meets a condition

Tags: go, slice, predicate

What would be the most elegant way to check if every item in a slice meets some condition? In my specific scenario, I have a slice of bytes: [16]byte. I need to check if all bytes are 0.

In JS, for example, I would do something like that:

```
const uint8Array = new Uint8Array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0])//Can be thought of as an array of "bytes"

const isEmpty = uint8Array.every(byte=>byte === 0)//Check that every "byte" is zero

console.log(isEmpty)//false
```

What's the cleanest and most straightforward way to do this in Go?

Comment: A nitpick: `[16]byte` in Go is an array, not a slice. Regarding the question: a simple `for` loop which sets a flag and exits immediately as soon as the condition is not met. `for … range` us usually the simplest. And no, Go does not have any language level primitives for writing indecipherable one-liners to do what you're after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For readability and flexibility (e.g. if you need to operate on types other than `byte`), you may benefit from writing a small `All` generic function that

- accepts a slice and a predicate on the element type of that slice, and
- returns `true` if and only if the predicate is satisfied for all elements of the slice.

You'll then be free to put that generic function to use with different slices and predicates.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    bs := []byte{15: 1} // slice of 16 bytes, all but the last one of which are zero
    isZero := func(b byte) bool { return b == 0 }
    fmt.Println(All(bs, isZero)) // false
}

func All[T any](ts []T, pred func(T) bool) bool {
    for _, t := range ts {
        if !pred(t) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

([Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/0em96zgRzy8))

No need to create a library for that `All` function, though; [a little copying is better than a little dependency](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAAkCSZUG1c&t=9m28s).

Answer (score 2):

It would be easy if you use the bytes package, here is an example :

```
func main() {
    n := []byte{0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
    b := bytes.ContainsRune(n, 1)
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

In bytes package there are multiple methods you can call for your result, like checking char, or multiple contains etc.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way is to use a range-based for loop, since as far as I'm aware, Go doesn't have built-in function similar to `.ForEach`.

If you don't need an index, you can omit it from the loop and you will have something similar:

```
isEmpty := true
for _, val := range uint8Array {
    if val != 0 {
        isEmpty=false
        break
    }
}

fmt.Println(isEmpty)
```

If you use the function repeatedly, you can define it as your own separate function as well.

```
func IsEmpty(arr *[]any) bool {
    for _, val := range *arr {
        if val != 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    
    return true
}
```

Although the last one might cause issues for some data types.